# How to play last x seconds of media file

Tags: c#, wpf, media-player, duration

I need to play last 20 seconds of audio file. I try to specify `Position` property of `myMediaPlayer`, but there is a problem. Because I try to play LAST seconds of file I cannot set `Position` property of audio file like this:

```
myMediaPlayer.Position = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 20);
```

I need to set `Position` property like this

```
myMediaPlayer.Position = new TimeSpan(0, 0, DURATION_OF_FILE - 20);
```

Computing of audio file duration is the problem. Firstly, I don't know duration of file, therefore I try to compute it in `MediaOpened` event handler.

```
void MediaOpened(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    _duration = myMediaElement.NaturalDuration.TimeSpan;
}
```

To invoke `MediaOpened` I need to start play audio file, so I am enforced to write in constructor:

```
// Just for MediaOpened call
myMediaElement.Play();

// I need not playing file right here, so I stop playing immediately
myMediaElement.Stop();
```

Now duration is computed and all seems to be good. But after that fake play-stop operations `myMediaPlayer` ignores `Position` property! Audio file is always opened from the beginning, from the first second whatever `Position` is set.

How can it be solved?

**XAML:**

```
<StackPanel>
    <MediaElement  Name="myMediaElement"
                    LoadedBehavior="Manual"/>
    <Button Click="SeekToMediaPosition">Click</Button>
</StackPanel>
```

**.cs**

```
TimeSpan _duration;

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    myMediaElement.Source = new Uri("D:/VS_Projects/WpfApplication1/WpfApplication1/Resources/Audio.mp3");
    myMediaElement.MediaOpened += new System.Windows.RoutedEventHandler(MediaOpened);

    myMediaElement.Play();
    myMediaElement.Stop();
}

void MediaOpened(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    _duration = myMediaElement.NaturalDuration.TimeSpan;
}


private void SeekToMediaPosition(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
{
    var test = (Int32)Math.Truncate(_duration.TotalSeconds) - 20;

    TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(0, 0, test);
    myMediaElement.Position = ts;
    myMediaElement.Play();
}
```

Comment: Add UnloadedBehavior="Manual" to the media element. Hope it works

Comment: It works, thx. You can form your comment as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add UnloadedBehavior="Manual" to the media element. Hope it works

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing `myMediaElement.Stop();`, do `myMediaElement.Pause();`.

Doing `Stop()` resets the player and does not allow you to set the `Position`.  Goofy, I know, but that's how it works.

Comment: Unfortunately, it does't work for me. But `Add UnloadedBehavior="Manual"` works.